# Swipe to dismiss notification on foreground service

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, foregroundnotification

I'm trying to dismiss a notification from the foreground service but yet find any solutions. I'm not using **`notificationManager.notify(...)`** but **`startForeground(...)`** instead.

My **NotificationCompat.Builder**

```
Intent actionCancelNotification = new Intent(MusicPlayerApp.getAppContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
actionCancelNotification.setAction(ACTION_DISMISS_NOTIFICATION);
actionCancelNotification.putExtra(PLAYBACK_NOTIFICATION_ID, PLAYBACK_NOTI_ID);

PendingIntent dismissNotiPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MusicPlayerApp.getAppContext(), 0, actionCancelNotification, 0);

    //NotificationCompat.Builder
builder.setCustomBigContentView(getRemoteView())
       .setContentTitle("SongPlayback Notification")
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_playback_notification_icon)
       .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MusicPlayerApp.getAppContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_playback_notification_icon))
       .setContentText("this is content text")
       .setSubText("sub text")
       .setDeleteIntent(dismissNotiPendingIntent)
       .build();
```

Even if i **setOnGoing(false);** it still did not work. I have followed this thread solution: [Make a notification from a foreground service cancelable once the service is not in foreground anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596709/make-a-notification-from-a-foreground-service-cancelable-once-the-service-is-not)

and this is the new **NotificationCompat.Builder** as the official document written:

```
//NotificationCompat.Builder
builder.setCustomBigContentView(getRemoteView())
       .setContentTitle("SongPlayback Notification")
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_playback_notification_icon)
       .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MusicPlayerApp.getAppContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_playback_notification_icon))
       .setContentText("this is content text")
       .setSubText("sub text")
       //this did not work too
       .setDeleteIntent(MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(MusicPlayerApp.getAppContext(), PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP)) //this d
       .build();
```

I wonder if any solutions to solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: What kind of Service you are using ? Is it `START_NOT_STICKY`?

Comment: yes, it is **START_NOT_STICKY**

Comment: I did mention this thread on my post above. I have tried the following solution from the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice.html  but it still did not work for me :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel a foreground service from using the notification (swipe dismiss) or clear all notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872204/how-to-cancel-a-foreground-service-from-using-the-notification-swipe-dismiss-o)

Comment: @Krot have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You can make the notification dismissible by swiping by;

```
stopForeground(false);
```

And to dismiss the notification totally;

```
stopForeground(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me exactly

```
stopForeground(true);
```